# How do I make a sharp edge to a shape?

Tags: modeling

I've been learning to model for a year now on and off and I'm pretty good at making perfect quad organic shapes without any 6 sided or more poles. But I don't know how to make a proper sharp edge to a shape.

On the left, if I use sculpting tools, including smooth, the verts all want to collapse away from the tear edge.

On the right, the verts are stable but I have the undesired 6 sided pole.

How do I properly make this sharp edge shape?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use Mean Crease or Autosmooth?

Comment: could you upload the file (or just this part of the model) ?

Comment: I tried the Blender manual and googleing "Mean Crease" nothing.

Comment: to me.. or I do not understand your question, or all depend on the upper part (which is not visible on the screen shot)... that's why I asked for an upload. What I mean : quad straight up seems to do the job (if we can not see the upper part)

Comment: All I would be uploading is a plane subdivided a few times with some edges separated with the [V] key.

Comment: Sure I understand that, so, simply have straight (to up) quads

Comment: Doesn't work, make that, then use smoothing it will bunch up all the edge verts.

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you want to obtain :

[image]

- Starting from a grid like in (1)
- Inset <kbd>I</kbd> the faces (2)
- Remove the top center point and, eventually, align the top (3)

[image]

At this step, the smooth makes a non sharp angle and some faces to 'correct' in the bottom part :

[image]

- Separate <kbd>V</kbd> the bottom center vertex and move it down a little (4)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then *edge slide* both sides to mark the angle (5)

[image]

Here the shading is not good :

[image]

This is due to the inner triangles which are badly oriented :

- Have a look (6), with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (triangulate)
- And correct it (7), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then *rotate edge CW (clockwise )*

[image]

- Come back to quads, selecting the faces and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (8)
- Sharpen the angle if you need, like previously with *edge slide* (9)

[image]

The topology is more or less tolerant to subsurf (which seems ok) or to bevel (which is not so ok). So, depending on what you want, you may need to adjust it :

[image]

[image]